# 411 error using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->credentials);

if ($action == 'post') {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-Type: application/json"));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     if(isset($params)){
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
     }
}
```

I am basically trying to mimic the following:

```
curl --user $APPLICATION_ID:$MASTER_KEY \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score": 1337, "playerName": "Sean Plott", "cheatMode": false }' \
  https://api.somewebsite.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

As of now $params is an array, not sure if this is correct or not.. should I json_encode the $params? How do I get rid of the 411 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http_build_query` is only for sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which yours isn't. Your POST data is probably messed up so you're not sending a `Content-Length` header with your request. Assuming you have your params as an array of those key-value pairs, you can use the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"score": 1337, "playerName": "Sean Plott", "cheatMode": false }');
```

Just pass the json string in directly. Your command line version isn't specifying a fieldname for this json data, so the PHP/curl version shouldn't either.

Comment: can I do json_encode ($array)? I tried that and it didn't work as well

Comment: Depends on what's in your array. if json-encode on it would produce the same json string, then sure.

Answer (score 0):

[411 Length Required](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.12) means the client (i.e. you) failed to specify a `Content-Length` header.

Since curl adds it automatically, but sets it to `-1` if you fail to give post data, `$param` is probably unset or `http_build_query` does not return what you expect. If you try just

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->credentials);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$json = '{"score": 1337, "playerName": "Sean Plott", "cheatMode": false}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

does the problem still occur?